# TypeError: Connecting Button in React Form to Function in a Different JavaScript File (MapboxGL)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, typeerror, mapbox

I have a React search form. When I click the search button in the `SearchForm.js` file, I want my map to zoom into a bounding box of the search results.

However, I keep getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null` in my `Map.js` file.

Here is an excerpt of the `SearchForm.js` file. I have a Material-UI button within a React form.

```
// some code omitted for example
return (
    <div
      className={classes.root}
    >
      <Form
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validate={validate}
        render={({ handleSubmit, values }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>
            // some code omitted for example
                <Button
                  id='searchButton'
                  variant="contained"
                  color="primary"
                  endIcon={<SearchIcon></SearchIcon>}
                  type="submit"
                  fullWidth
                >
                  Search
                </Button>
             // some code omitted for example
          </form>
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

Here is the `Map.js` file. My values for `maxWest`, `maxSouth`, `maxEast`, and `maxNorth` are hard-coded for the time being since I am working on the UI at the moment. At the top of the `Map.js` file, I am sure to import `SearchForm.js` by using the line `import SearchForm from './SearchForm.js';`.

```
var northEast = [131.308594, 46.195042];
var southEast = [117.597656, 8.233237];
var southWest = [79.101563, 32.842674];
var northWest = [86.847656, 44.715514];

...

var maxSouth = Math.min(southEast[1], southWest[1]);
var maxWest = Math.min(southWest[0], northWest[0]);
var maxNorth = Math.max(northWest[1], northEast[1]);
var maxEast = Math.max(northEast[0], southEast[0]);

// The error is from the addEventListener() *******************
document.getElementById('searchButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
        map.fitBounds([
          [maxWest - 5, maxSouth - 5], // southwestern corner of the bounds
          [maxEast + 5, maxNorth + 5] // northeastern corner of the bounds
        ]);
      });
```

I'm not sure what I am missing, and I do not understand why I am getting this error. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Does this help](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/use-mapbox-gl-js-with-react/)? @325

Comment: @Andy unfortunately, no. I actually tried following that, but they are not using different components in the example they have.