# React: Calling Function From Another Component (Specific Example)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, components

I am trying to better understand React, so I made this toy example to try and get a React component to call a function from another component. I am looking at the React Dev tools on Chrome, but nothing is being logged to the console. I'm not sure why this is the case. Could someone explain to me why this is wrong and how to fix it?

TestButton.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

export default function TestButton() {
  return(
    <div>
      <Button
    id='searchButton'
    variant="contained"
    color="primary"
    type="submit"
    fullWidth
    onClick={testFunction}
  >
    Search
  </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

App.js file:

```
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header.js';
import TestButton from './components/TestButton.js';

function testFunction() {
  console.log("Yay it works!");
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <TestButton></TestButton>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `testFunction` is neither exported from `App.js`, nor imported in `TestButton.js`. It doesn't extist at all in `TestButton.js`.

Comment: @tkausl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68545994/typeerror-calling-function-in-react-form-to-zoom-on-click-mapboxgl would you happen to know the answer to this question then?

Comment: Not sure if it's 100% exactly what you're trying to do, but here's a simple tutorial that worked for me: [how to call a function from another component](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UW-dskGK7II)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a reference to `testFunction` from `App` into `TestButton`.  Something like this:

```
export default function TestButton({fn}) {
  return(
    <div>
      <Button
        id='searchButton'
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        type="submit"
        fullWidth
        onClick={fn}
      >
        Search
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  function testFunction() {
    console.log("Yay it works!");
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <TestButton fn={testFunction}></TestButton>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The way you have it, testFunction is not in scope for the `TestButton` component, so passing in a function that your TestButton can use as a callback is a way to accomplish this.

Comment: Could I pass onClick={fn} as a prop from TestButton to App? @Chris Farmer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68545994/typeerror-calling-function-in-react-form-to-zoom-on-click-mapboxgl would you happen to know the answer to this question then?

Answer (score 1):

Your `App` component needs to explicitly pass a reference to the function to the `TestButton` component:

```
<TestButton testFunction={testFunction}></TestButton>
```

and your `TestButton` component needs to accept the property object that's passed to it. From there you can destructure the function and use it.

```
export default function TestButton({ testFunction }) {
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68545994/typeerror-calling-function-in-react-form-to-zoom-on-click-mapboxgl would you happen to know the answer to this question then?